# Prevent elements from overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm using JointJS to generate dinamically diagrams.

The problem I encountered is that my elements have different heights that's why i can't set the position manually.

I made a function to generate random coordinates which work pretty nice. I used the smart routing script to prevent links from overlapping with other elements.

But my problem is that my elements overlap each other when generated.

I searched a lot but didn't find anything which could do what I want.

Is there a way to prevent them from overlapping like it's done with links ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This might fix the issue of overlapping

```css
#yourelement{
  clear:both;
  }
```